# highlighting letter of word matching audio file

Tags: android

I've one audio file that spells a word. I want to highlight each letter of the word matching the audio. I know how to highlight one letter in a word. I can't figure out how to identify which letter is being pronounced in the audio to highlight the correct letter in the word.

My idea so far based on experience with other programming language:

Split the audio file into multiple small files and add even complete listener and play them one by one matching the letter. Or use some API if possible like play playAudio(src,from_this_position, to_this_postion) and add complete event to this and keep on playing the same audio file from different position for each letters.

Any better suggestions? If my idea is correct I'd really appreciate if I can get some snippets  on how to do so specially add event and play next sound.

Comment: Your approach sounds the simplest, but it could prove to be a lot of manual data entry work the more words you have. So the question is, how many words are you really going to have? If you're going to have many, I would try to find a way to automate the data entry as much as possible. I would play all the sounds in one go, and I'd press a key down each time to record the timestamp each time a new letter/syllable needs to be shown. And I'd keep two arrays for each sound file, one array to keep track of each timestamp and one array to keep track of each letter/syllable.

Comment: Plus, if it's a teaching application, the application may not even need to make each letter disappear (or be less highlighted) each time there is silence or a pause between each sound or each word. And I would test out the usability of this issue with friends before I'd invest too much time coding it one way or another.

Comment: There will be only 26 words for now, one for each alphabet. I'd really want to highlight each word as well to make it clear to children.

Comment: Forget what I said then. The first idea you had should work just fine: "Splitting the audio file into multiple small files and ..." You could even do a video sequence for each word, if you want to simplify your work even more.

Comment: What do you mean by video sequence for each word? Do you have a snippet to play audio file and play next one on completion of one?

Comment: I just meant that you could just video-record the highlighting of the word while you're saying it. If you're really-really lazy, you could even video-record each highlight while you say all the 26 words in one go, and just post it as one video on youtube (no programming even necessary!!). For your original idea, which would work too, I'm too tired and too lazy to hunt down the right snippets of code. I'll let someone else do that part (perhaps, you could even do that part).